# Return multiple items

Tags: python, sdk, ebay-api

i am new to python as a matter of fact, this is my first python project. I am using ebaysdk to search for electronics on ebay and i want it to return multiple results because my app is for comparing prices but it returns only one result.

Someone please help me to make the code return multiple results.

Here is my code snippet.

```
@app.route('/ebay_page_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ebay_page_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #Get json format of the text sent by Ajax
        search = request.json['search']

        try:
            #ebaysdk code starts here
            api = finding(appid='JohnOkek-hybridse-PRD-5c2330105-9bbb62f2', config_file = None)
            api_request = {'keywords':search, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo', 'categoryId': '293'}
            response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

            totalentries = int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
            items = soup.find_all('item')

            for item in items:
                cat = item.categoryname.string.lower()
                title = item.title.string.lower().strip()
                price = int(round(float(item.currentprice.string)))
                url = item.viewitemurl.string.lower()
                seller = item.sellerusername.text.lower()
                listingtype = item.listingtype.string.lower()
                condition = item.conditiondisplayname.string.lower()

                print ('____________________________________________________________')

                #return json format of the result for Ajax processing
                return jsonify(cat + '|' + title + '|' + str(price) + '|' + url + '|' + seller + '|' + listingtype + '|' + condition)
        except ConnectionError as e:
            return jsonify(e)
```

Comment: untab your first `return`, you're putting it in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

[Click here to see how i did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137415/return-multiple-items-for-ajax/53423205#53423205)

Thanks to every contributor, i am most grateful to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, added the key value pair collection example you could use :

```
@app.route('/ebay_page_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ebay_page_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #Get json format of the text sent by Ajax
        search = request.json['search']

        try:

            #ebaysdk code starts here
            api = finding(appid='JohnOkek-hybridse-PRD-5c2330105-9bbb62f2', config_file = None)
        api_request = {'keywords':search, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo', 'categoryId': '293'}
        response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

        totalentries = int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
        items = soup.find_all('item')

        # This will be returned
        itemsFound = {}

        # This index will be incremented 
        # each time an item is added
        index = 0

        for item in items:
            cat = item.categoryname.string.lower()
            title = item.title.string.lower().strip()
            price = int(round(float(item.currentprice.string)))
            url = item.viewitemurl.string.lower()
            seller = item.sellerusername.text.lower()
            listingtype = item.listingtype.string.lower()
            condition = item.conditiondisplayname.string.lower()

            # Adding the item found in the collection
            # index is the key and the item json is the value
            itemsFound[index] = jsonify(cat + '|' + title + '|' + str(price) + '|' + url + '|' + seller + '|' + listingtype + '|' + condition)

            # Increment the index for the next items key
            index++

        for key in itemsFound: 
            print key, ':', itemsFound[key

        # return itemsFound

    except ConnectionError as e:
        return jsonify(e)
```

Comment: I tried that snippet and get this error when i tried running the code.



index++
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Solved it by changing index++ to index+=1 and run the code and it worked but it doesn't return any result; it says /TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable/

Comment: how are accessing the values, you need the index key to retrieve the value

Comment: I'll try to figure it out from here but i am most grateful to you for guiding me. You pointed me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Show me the line where you are reading the values...remember to use square brackets like itemsFound[1] would return the second item found in the list

Comment: return itemsFound

That is the line i am using. Isn't there a way i can get all the values from the dictionary?

Comment: Replace return itemsFound with ` for key in itemsFound:
    print key, ':', itemsFound[key] `

Comment: Got this error after trying that. /raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
/

Answer (score 0):

Once the first item is found, add it to the collection. After your for loop finishes, then return the collection.

Right now you are returning (breaking the iteration) once you have found the first

Comment: simply untabing the first return as suggested by Rocky Li will return only the last item found

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet to show how that is done?

Comment: itemsReturned = {}

Comment: I am really sorry Max but i really can't make out how to use that code. I am a big time rookie in python.