# Return multiple items for Ajax

Tags: python, ebay-api

I have this python code that searches ebay to return results for a serach string. The codes executes properly and returns the result as i want but only when i use the **print()** function. I am parsing the result using json to a flask page, using print() only prints to the console so i used return but it doesn't give all the results, it returns only one item.

How do i make the code return all the results and display it on my flask page?

I am new to python and this is my first project. I have asked this question before and got the code upgraded to what it is now and i have been scouring the internet for solution but i haven't found any yet. Someone please help me with a code that will return all the results gotten from the search.

[Link to my previous question that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105654/return-multiple-items)

Backend

```
@app.route('/ebay_page_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ebay_page_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #Get json format of the text sent by Ajax
        search = request.json['search']

        try:
            #ebaysdk code starts here
            api = finding(appid='JohnOkek-hybridse-PRD-5c2330105-9bbb62f2', config_file = None)
            api_request = {'keywords':search, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo', 'categoryId': '293'}
            response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

            totalentries = int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
            items = soup.find_all('item')

            # This will be returned
            itemsFound = {}

            # This index will be incremented 
            # each time an item is added
            index = 0

            for item in items:
                cat = item.categoryname.string.lower()
                title = item.title.string.lower().strip()
                price = int(round(float(item.currentprice.string)))
                url = item.viewitemurl.string.lower()
                seller = item.sellerusername.text.lower()
                listingtype = item.listingtype.string.lower()
                condition = item.conditiondisplayname.string.lower()

                print ('____________________________________________________________')

                #return json format of the result for Ajax processing
            #return jsonify(cat + '|' + title + '|' + str(price) + '|' + url + '|' + seller + '|' + listingtype + '|' + condition)

                # Adding the item found in the collection
                # index is the key and the item json is the value
                itemsFound[index] = jsonify(cat + '|' + title + '|' + str(price) + '|' + url + '|' + seller + '|' + listingtype + '|' + condition)

                # Increment the index for the next items key
                index+=1

            for key in itemsFound:
                return itemsFound[key]

        except ConnectionError as e:
            return jsonify(e)
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".button").click(function() {
                var search = $(".search").val().trim();
                if (search) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{{url_for('ebay_page_post')}}",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'search': search }),
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data) {
                            if (data.indexOf("|") >= 0) {
                                var newData = data.split("|");
                                var category = newData[0];
                                var title = newData[1];
                                var price = newData[2]
                                var url = newData[3];
                                var seller = newData[4];
                                var listingType = newData[5];
                                var condition = newData[6];


                                $("#returned").html("");
                                $("#returned").append(returned(category, title, price, url, seller, listingType, condition));
                            } else {
                                $("#returned").html("<label>"+data+"</label>");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });


        function returned(category, title, price, url, seller, listingType, condition) {
            return '<div class="col-lg-6"> ' +
                            '<div class="box">'+
                                '<div class="icon"><i class="ion-ios-heart-outline"></i></div>' +
                                '<h4 class="title">'+title+'</h4>' +
                                '<h5>'+category+'</h5>' +
                                '<small><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">Go to site</a></small>'+
                                '<div class="description">' +
                                    'Price: <strong>'+price+'</strong>' +
                                    '<p>Seller: <strong>'+seller+'</strong></p>' +
                                    '<p>'+listingType+'</p>' +
                                    '<p>Condition: '+condition+'</p>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by modifying my code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import pprint
import locale
import time
import datetime
import ebaysdk
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template, jsonify


HTML_OUTPUT = """
    <div class=\"col-lg-6\">
        <div class=\"box wow fadeInLeft\">
            <div class=\"icon\"><img src=\"%s\" alt=\"Item Image\"></div>
            <h4 class=\"title\">%s</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Price: $ %s</li>
                <li>Seller: %s</li>
                <li>Condition: %s</li>
                <li>Listing Type: %s</li>
            </ul>
            <small><a href="%s" target="_blank">Go to site</a></small>
        </div>
    </div>"""

# Instantiate our Flask class.
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True


# Decide which URL will trigger everything...
@app.route('/')
def ebay_serve_page():
    empty_folder()
    return render_template("index.html")

def empty_folder():
    folder = 'static'
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            #elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

# Grab search string entered by user...
@app.route('/ebay_page_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ebay_page_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #Get json format of the text sent by Ajax
        search = request.json['search']

        try:
            #ebaysdk code starts here
            api = finding(appid='JohnOkek-hybridse-PRD-5c2330105-9bbb62f2', config_file = None)
            api_request = {'keywords':search, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo', 'categoryId': '293'}
            response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

            items = soup.find_all('item')

            # This will be returned
            items_found = []

            for item in items:
                pic = item.PictureURL
                title = item.title.string.strip()
                price = float(item.currentprice.string)
                url = item.viewitemurl.string.lower()
                seller = item.sellerusername.text
                listingtype = item.listingtype.string
                condition = item.conditiondisplayname.string

                print ('____________________________________________________________')

                # Adding the item found in the collection
                items_found.append(HTML_OUTPUT % (pic,
                                                title,
                                                price,
                                                seller,
                                                condition,
                                                listingtype,
                                                url))

            f = open("static/"+search+".html", 'w+')
            for item in items_found:
                f.write("%s" % item)
            f.close()
            return "1"

        except ConnectionError as e:
            return jsonify(e)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Then i modified my ajax call to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {
            var search = $(".search").val().trim();
            var file = search + ".html";
            if (search) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{{url_for('ebay_page_post')}}",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'search': search }),
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"/static/"+file,
                                dataType:'html',
                                success: function(items){
                                    $('#returned').html(items);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            $("#returned").html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

To see the result [check it out here](https://nuksearch.herokuapp.com)

Thanks to every one who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your python code is only return the first item from your `itemsFound` list because that is what you are telling it to do:

```
 for key in itemsFound:
     return itemsFound[key]
```

… why not just return the whole list?  Like so

```
 return itemsFound
```

Comment: I tried it but it returns this error: /TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable/

Comment: You should post the full error stack trace.

Comment: [2018-11-12 15:10:57,487] ERROR in app: Exception on /ebay_page_post [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: There is the full stack trace for the error is got.
I broke it because of character limitation.